# Sonar : lambda - Remove useless curly braces around statement

Tags: lambda, java-8, sonarqube

These code examples:

```
import java.util.Observer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observer observer = (o, arg) -> {
            if (arg != null) {
                System.out.println(arg);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Observer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observer observer = (o, arg) -> {
            try {
                String test = (String) arg;
                ...
            }
            catch (ClassCastException e) {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

are noncompliant with this [sonarqube rule](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1602):

> Lamdbas containing only one statement should not nest this statement
>   in a block : Remove useless curly braces around statement

how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The classification of these curly braces as “useless” is wrong.

You can omit curly braces around a single *expression statement*, that is, for example, a method invocation, a `new` expression, or `x++`, `x+=y`, etc.

Or you can transform a sole `… -> { return x; }` statement into an expression `… -> x`.

But you can’t omit curly braces around every single statement.

You can’t fix that. The only thing you can do is file a bug report.

By the way, even then, removing them is not necessarily a readability improvement. It depends…

Comment: Great answer, I'll just add the bug report here : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-552 Thanks.

Comment: It seems that your bug isn't there - the correct issue is here 
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/incorrect-inconsistent-sonar-squid-rule-regarding-lambdas-and-curly-braces-squid-s1604/17141